# TFS 2012: build never starting for continuous/rolling after upgrade from 2010

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild

With build definitions that worked fine for TFS 2010 and after some template editing for 2012, I now have build definitions that run fine on 2012 with my build controller setup (also upgraded from 2010 to 2012) - but only when started manually.

When I set them to continuous or rolling (they were set that way, but I changed it to and back just to see if that update changed anything), even though there are lots of checkins in relevant folders (active folders), nothing happens. The definitions also are enabled, not set to paused or disabled.

Why don't they start, how to make them work automatically again?

update:

Nothing arrives on the build controller. Queue is empty.
Also, I just created a dummy-bogus build definition using the default template (just to make sure it is not the custom template), here nothing happens as well when checking in on an active folder (active meaning I defined it as active in the build definition workspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting back to the admin, it seems they installed some tool on the TFS server that broke the event mechanism. Tool removed, problem fixed, and now they will have to search for a tool (mail notification) that does not break the build events.

Thx!

Comment: Tool uninstalled. Simple. As for more details: it was someone else (admin) who installed it in the first place, plus, it was an additional tool (in this case proprietary) and they (you?) would know what was installed and might break anything. Nothing much more to say.. admin fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the builds being queued? If so, then check the permissions of the user that is selected to execute the builds, maybe there is a permission that is blocking it.

Comment: No, queue stays empty. It seems that nothing at all happens on a checkin.